# Import ZIP file options broken in Mathematica 12.2.0

Tags: import, compression, version-12.2

I am trying to read a zipped table, which has its entries separated by colons. In Mathematica 12.1.1 (and earlier) this worked well with the following command:

```
Import[
  "test.zip",
  {"produkt*", "Table"},
  "FieldSeparators" -> {";"}
][[1]];
```

In Mathematica 12.2.0 the colons are no longer recognised. This looks like a bug to me, or has the syntax changed? Has anyone noticed this as well?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately this is indeed a bug and it's fixed for the next version. The workaround is to use `ExtractArchive` first, then `Import` the resulting files. You can extract specific files from an archive using the 3rd argument.